# integrity problem loading x.509 certificate (-65) in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04, uefi

I am having problem booting Ubuntu 20.04. Recently I upgrade to 20.04 from 18.04. After installation and a several successful reboot, I cannot boot 20.04 anymore. It is showing

```
integrity problem loading x.509 certificate (-65) ubuntu 20.04
```

I have already set the `BOOT Mode: UEFI` and `Secure Boot: Disabled`. Previously I had dual boot of Ubuntu along with Windows 10 and having this problem. To make sure that Windows 10 is not
causing problem, now I have removed it. So its only Ubuntu now in the system.
My system is :

- Acer Aspire A515-52G
- HDD: Toshiba 1 TB
- Have Intel Optane memory of 16 GB but 'Disabled' from BOOT menu.

Can anyone please help with any suggestions to get rid of this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If "Secure Boot" is disabled then I would strongly recommend testing your hard drive for bad blocks. You will need an Ubuntu Live USB/DVD to do this, so be sure to have one handy.

0. Boot into a Live USB/DVD session
1. Open a terminal
2. If you do not know where your Ubuntu installation is installed (For example: `/dev/sda2`), let's find out. Type this in the terminal:

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l
   ```

   You're going to see a lot of information go past on your screen. Scroll up until you see the record for your Toshiba hard drive. It will look something like this:

   ```
   Disk identifier: D846D15F-9BF1-4583-B863-24DD1902198D

   Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
   /dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    2000895   1998848   976M EFI System
   /dev/nvme0n1p2   2000896  936214527 934213632 445.5G Linux filesystem
   /dev/nvme0n1p3 936214528 1000214527  64000000  30.5G Linux swap
   ```

   Yours will probably have device names like `/dev/sdaX` or `/dev/sdbY`. One of these will be where you installed Ubuntu. The type will likely say `Linux filesystem`. Remember (or write down) this device name.
3. Now let's test for bad blocks using the following command:

   ```
   sudo badblocks -sv /dev/sda
   ```

   ***Note:** Be sure to change* `/dev/sda` *to whatever device name has your Linux installation. You do not need to have the number. So if Ubuntu is installed on* `/dev/sda3`, *just type* `/dev/sda`.

   This process may take a long, long time depending on how quickly the computer can scan the entire 1TB drive. You may want to consider having the task run overnight.

   When the system is done running `badblocks` it will provide a report letting you know if there is anything wrong with the hard drive. If there is, then it's time to replace your Toshiba HDD with something else. You may be able to *temporarily* repair the drive by running `sudo fsck /dev/sda2` (with the appropriate number in the device name, as reported by the output of `badblocks`), but you do not want to put too much faith in a hard drive that reports errors.

   If no errors are reported, then it will be important to confirm that "Secure Boot" is disabled in the BIOS. These are generally the two things that can cause Ubuntu to report the integrity problem.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detail answer. Actually I have tried everything else. So the only possibility that remained is if the HDD have some badblocks. Started the checking just now as you have told. Let's see if it is the case.

Comment: Finally the checking is done and my HDD has a lot (in millions) of bad blocks. 
Thanks by the way for the suggestions.

Comment: Ouch. Glad you could confirm the issue.