# Error during booting "integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65" and others

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 22.04

I dual boot Windows 11 & Ubuntu 22.04, and right after I choose Ubuntu from the GRUB menu, I get the following errors:

[integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rtudm.jpg)

The above screen shows momentarily and Ubuntu seems to continue to boot fine regardless.

I was able to solve the one related to VMX by enabling VMX from my BIOS settings, whereas I wasn't able to find anything there related to SGX (I don't know if it's listed in my settings under a different alias), and I don't really know the meaning of the one related to "integrity".

Does anyone have an idea about the source of these errors, especially the "integrity" one?

Comment: step 1: disable secure boot. step 2: check your hard drive for bad sectors. These are the most common causes for this error that I could find. However, errors at boot that don't affect normal operation of the OS once it's booted are normal and can be ignored.

Comment: @Esther I'm experiencing the same error. how do i check the hard drive for bad sectors?

Comment: @user3710760 you can follow the instructions in the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310107/integrity-problem-loading-x-509-certificate-65-in-ubuntu-20-04?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I do this in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

It will shutdown, after that has been working here.